# How to organize multiselect dropdownlist using kartik-select2 extension

Tags: php, list, yii2, multi-select, dropdown

I need to organize multiselect dropdownlist. I tried like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'receiver_id')->widget(Select2::classname(),
    [ 'data' => ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),'id','username'),
        'options' =>
            ['placeholder' => 'Select receivers...', 'multiple' => true],
        'pluginOptions' =>
            [ 'tags' => true,
                'maximumInputLength' => 10
            ],
    ]);
?>
```

In the view it seems correctly, in the textfield receivers appear one by one, but when I press "Send" button it says that Receiver ID must be an integer. How can I solve this issue? I need to duplicate one db record for different receivers which I select using select2 dropdown list. For example, I choose in dropdownlist user1 and user2, "Send" action should work twice accordingly. In the db table named as 'letter' should be two same records with different id and receiver_id.

My actionCreate function in the Controller class:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Letter();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        foreach($model->receiver_id as $r_id){
            $save = new Letter();
            $save->type_id = $model->type_id;
            $save->subject = $model->subject;
            $save->body = $model->body;
            $save->sender_id = $model->sender_id;
            $save->start_date = $model->start_date;
            $save->end_date = $model->end_date;
            $save->receiver_id = $r_id;
            $save->save();
        }
        $model->attachment = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'attachment');
        $filename = pathinfo($model->attachment , PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $ext = pathinfo($model->attachment , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $newFname = $filename.'.'.$ext;

        $path=Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/uploads/';
        if(!empty($newFname)){
            $model->attachment->saveAs($path.$newFname);
            $model->attachment = $newFname;
            if($model->save()){
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

My IDE says on "$model->receiver_id" that "Expected types array or object, Actual: int"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to change rule of the `receiver_id` attribute.

Comment: What the rule  do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

do receiver_id as array on your model; and

```
foreach($model->receiver_id as $r_id){
    $save = new YourModel();
    $save->yourProperty = $model->yourProperty;
    ....
    $save->receiver_id = $r_id;
    $save->save();
}
```

Comment: Need I add this loop into actionCreate method?

Comment: Yeap on actionCreate

Comment: Could you specify how to do this "do receiver_id as array on your model"?

Comment: It says "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: I think it's not enough to change receiver_id to array only in view. What do you think?

Comment: try{if($model->load($_POST){// there is foreach ......})} ............. do after posting data

Comment: edit question and add your current actionCreate there

Comment: My IDE says on "$model->receiver_id" that "Expected types array or object, Actual: int"